# Does Python support Isometric photos?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm planning on making a game like "Polytopia" (http://polytopia.wikia.com/wiki/The_Battle_of_Polytopia_Wikia). So I will be making assets like the soldiers and castles but they are 'Isometric photos'. I am going to be using tkinter in Python but I don't know if tkinter actually supports isometric photos?
If anyone has any advice on making this game for me I'm open to it ^^
Thank you.

Comment: isometric just describes a specific angle from which the content of the images are shown. Technically they are not different from other images, so as long as tkinter can show images you are fine. I've never used tkinter but I had the impression that it is more suited for "business applications" with buttons etc. and less suited for games.

Comment: You can also use `pygame`.